# Keep numbers as floats when a column has a mix of numbers and asterisks (i.e *'s)

Tags: pandas

I'm using a dataset from the US Bureau of Labor Statistics. The particular table I'm working with is wage data for various occupations. When a particular occupation doesn't have wage data, they use asterisks (i.e *'s) making the column a mix of numbers and *'s.

This causes pandas to convert the column to a `dtype=object` and all the numbers become strings. My work around has been to cast them to a float() when I need to work with them a numbers, but this still seems to create an unnecessary upfront memory allocation. Am I correct in my thinking here? If so, does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve this?

Comment: The ideal way would be to use to_numeric which will convert the * to NaN. Something like, df['Float_col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Float_col'], errors = 'coerce')

Comment: @Vaishali, thanks for the tip. What if I want to do this before I initialize the dataframe? Could I do this conversion as part of my read_csv() setup?

Comment: You can use the dtype parameter, dtype = {float_col : np.float}

Comment: @Vaishali When I do that though, I get a `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '*'`

Comment: Never mind, I looked into the documentation and found the paramater: `na_values` and simply set `na_values = "*"`